# MongoDB - Error while trying to show server startup warnings: no such cmd

Tags: mongodb

Instalei algumas das versões do mongodb num Macbook com Yosemite 10.10.2 e tanto usando o homebrew, quanto instalando manualmente, todas deram o mesmo erro, exceto a `1.4.4` que é muito antiga, já veio instalada e não me interessa muito:

```
$ mongo
MongoDB shell version: 3.0.0
connecting to: test
Error while trying to show server startup warnings: no such cmd
>
```

[image: Error while trying to show server startup warnings: no such cmd]

Perdi uma manhã (o que já acho uma eternidade) pesquisando e não encontrei muita coisa a respeito.
Esses dois links foram o que aparentemente chegaram mais próximo de uma solução

- https://github.com/bobthecow/genghis/issues/94
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18194160/error-with-mongo-client

O último diz que encontrou a solução atualizando a versão do server, mas, também não faço idéia de como funcionou pra ele, certamente esqueci algo.

Alguém já teve esse problema?

Comment: Você consegue utilizar o client normalmente mesmo com o erro? Percebi que o prompt está aparecendo na screenshot.

Comment: Não conseguia, resolvi, mas infelizmente não descobri o porque, não tinha instalado nada além do mongo, npm e do homebrew, mas fiz a reinstalação do sistema e resolveu.